# Is the "mobile" subdomain popular practice in non-English websites as well (e.g. móvil, mobiel)?

Tags: mobile

For example, there is mobile.twitter.com, mobile.facebook.com... So I'm wondering if that practice is common in other languages, like, móvil.popularSpanishSite.com or mobiel.popularDutchSite.com, etc...Is another similar word used, like célula.popularSpanishSite.com (célula = cell)?

Being an English-only speaker, I'm not sure how I would research this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most popular ones are: mobile.yoursite.com and m.yoursite.com

I have encountered some others like "lajt.yoursite.com" (Polish site), but there are only few of them and they're not recognizable among common users.